# BBEdit Grep/Regex find and replace part after dash

Tags: regex, grep, bbedit

What should the regular expression look like when I want to find and remove the part that begins with a dash (-) and everything after in the Article number column?

I'm using BBEdit to search and replace the strings in a tab delimited CSV-file (sample below).

```
"Article number"    "Name"  "Third Column"
"Shorts Artic"  "Swa..."    "2018-07-28"
"Shorts Artic-1"    "Swa..."    ""
"Shorts Artic-2-1"  "Swa..."    "https://test-domain.com/..."
"Shorts Artic-2-2-1"    "Sw..." ""
"Shorts Artic-2-2-2-2-1"    "Ba..." "-asd"
"Shorts Artic-2-2-2-2-2-1"  "Nus..."
"Shorts Artic-2-2-2-2-2-1-1"    "Lek.."
"0858-1"    "Jacket Blue.."
"0858-2-1"  "Jacket Re.."
"0858-2-2-1"    "Int..."
"0858-2-2-2-1"  "In..."
"0858-2-2-2-2-1"    "Int..."
"0858-2-2-2-2-2-1"  "Int..."
"0858-2-2-2-2-2-2-1"    "Int..."
"0858-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1"  "In..."
"0858-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2"  "In..."
"0858-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1"  "In..." "6 107-124 cm"
"stl 31-35-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-1-1"   "In..."
```

`"Shorts Artic-1"` would turn into `"Shorts Artic"`

`"Shorts Artic-2-2-1"` would turn into `"Shorts Artic"`

`"0858-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2"` would turn into `"0858"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
("[a-zA-Z 0-9]+)(?:-\d)+(?=")
```

- `("[a-zA-Z 0-9]+)` Match and capture `"`, alphabetic characters, whitespace and digits.
- `(?:-\d)+` Non capturing group. Match and capture `-` and digits repeatedly.
- `(?=")` Positive lookahead for `"`.

Replace with:

```
 \1
```

You can try the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/fb5rEY/3).

---

For the updated text file, you can use:

```
^"((?:[a-zA-z]+ ?)+|[0-9]+)(?:-?\d)+(?=")
```

Replacing with:

```
"\1
```

You can try the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/fb5rEY/4).

Comment: Very close. But it's not matching "stl 31-35-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-1-1" and if there's a date in the second/third column it's matching the date "2018-07-28". I updated my sample data.

Comment: @petsk No problem, but I don't like leaving problems unsolved :P [See the second pattern in the updated answer](https://regex101.com/r/fb5rEY/4).